# If $E \subset\mathbb R$ is compact and nonempty. Prove $\sup (E)$, $\inf (E) \in E$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb R$ is compact and nonempty. Prove $\sup (E)$, $\inf (E)\in E$.

attempt: Suppose $E$ is compact, then $E$ is closed and bounded. Thus $\sup(E)$ and $\inf (E)$ exist. 
let $a = \sup(E)$, then there is a sequence $x_n \in E$ such that $x_n \to a$. Since $E$ is closed, then $a \in E$. Thus $\sup (E) \in E$.

Is this correct? Any feedback would really help. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's right.

Comment: Looks copacetic.

Comment: Does this generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato what are $\sup$ and $\inf$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Fair point, would need to define some order relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Depending on the rigor required, the following intuition may also pass:

The supremum of a set is always either contained in the set or is a limit point of the set. Since a compact set by definition contains all its limit points, it must contain its supremum. Similar for infimum.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this proof is the statement: "there is a sequence $x_n \rightarrow a$". Why does it exist?

First of all, this is a theorem 2.28 in *Rudin*, so you may compare you proof with it.

A closed set is defined in terms of limit points, not sequences. You may prove a characterisation of a limit point in terms of sequences (see theorem 3.2.5 in *Abbot*), but it's better to use here just definition.

We have first to prove that for **any** set $E$ we have $sup\ E \in \bar{E}$. In other words, like stated above, there's only 2 possibilities: 1) $sup\ E \in E$ or 2) $sup\ E$ is a limit point of $E$. In any case it's clear that a closed set contains its $sup$.

The proof goes like this (in notation from *Rudin*, $y = sup\ E$): fix some $h > 0$, we may find a point $x \in E$ s.t. $y - h < x < y$ for otherwise y - h would be an upper bound.

This is the gist of the proof. Of course, you may construct your $x_n$ using the similar argument like set a sequence of $h_n = 1/n$ and so on. But without this construction and also without mentioning the criterion for a limit point this is not a full proof. This is a very basic result and supposed to be proved from the ground up.

I should also notice that this proof in *Rudin* basically repeats the alternative characterisation of a $sup$ - see lemma 1.3.8 in *Abbot*.